# What is meant by the duality and homomorphism of an encryption algorithm?

Tags: rsa, algorithm-design

I am new to the field of cryptography and security so spare me with this question. What is the general idea of duality and homomorphism of an encryption algorithm? And how one may prove those two properties of a real-world encryption algorithm (e.g:- say for RSA encryption).

Comment: Where did you encounter these terms (especially "duality")?

Comment: I found this as a part of a question given in a post grad. security engineering course (which I am not currently taking as I am only an under grad.) in my university. What I wanted to find was a basic understanding of these terms (maybe an insight) as I am interested in encryption algorithms.

Comment: Homomorphism is a standard property of some encryption schemes, but I have to admit I have _never_ before heard of "duality" in the context of RSA or similar encryption schemes. The best I could imagine is the fact that RSA can be used for encryption and signature with the same core-operation.

Comment: Can it have a similar idea to that of the duality of a function in mathematics? I am just guessing